# update null primary key in a trigger using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, primary-key

I'm migrating our system from Oracle to SQL SERVER. In Oracle we have insert triggers that are resposnible for setting primary key if not set. Below you will find code from PL/SQL.

```
create or replace trigger trigg1
 before insert on table1
  for each row
   when (new.ID_T1 is null) -- if primary key is null
 begin
   select OUR_SEQ.nextval into :new.ID_T1 from dual;
end trigg1;
```

Now I have to do something similar in T-SQL. I found the solution, but unfortunatelly I have to list all the columns for the table trigger is created. This is something I want to avoid (model for the system is still very dynamic).

Is it possible to implement such trigger without listing all the columns in trigger?

Marcin

Comment: Just define your PK column to be `INT IDENTITY` and let SQL Server handle all the hard work for you !

Comment: Thanks for reply,  This would be too easy :) Sometimes PK is set from client application.

Comment: Gosh - and then you have to check and make sure that value isn't already being used?? This is **madness** - seriously : stop doing that. Don't let the user in the UI pick a PK!

Comment: It's not as bad as you mentioned :) PK is set by application by using sequence. User of course has no possibility to manipulate PK.

Comment: Since SQL Server (before version 2012) doesn't have sequences - I would still recommend: change your app and let SQL Server handle all PK generation.

Comment: The problem with sequence is already solved. Redesign is something i want to avoid (the way you proposed will have impact on performance in crutial part of the system)

Comment: You can definitely write this trigger in T-SQL, too - it would have to be a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger (SQL Server doesn't have any `BEFORE xxxx` triggers), and you need to take into account it'll be called ONCE for the batch (which could be affecting multiple rows) - not once per row. If you detect PK column being NULL, just set its value to that sequence value you say you've already handled.

Comment: I tried that way. I created cursor over inserted table and changed the PK to the one from the sequence. The problem is that with such solution I had to list all the columns and as I wrote before I'm looking for solution where I don't have to list all the columns

Comment: No, you'll have to list all of the columns. And the definition of the column will have to allow NULLs, which means you won't be able to declare it as a primary key.